# Annotation along a curve in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I add tick annotation along a curve in matplotlib? For example, suppose I want to produce this [image: figure].

I'd like to show values (520, 540, 560, ...) as well as the "ticks" (those small line segments perpendicular to the curve). Is there an easy way to do that? (Assuming I have a list of 3-tuples (x,y,wavelength) as an `np.ndarray` in hand.)

Here's some example code and data to play with, and the `cc2012xyz2_5_5dp.csv` file can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4y85wzgzj4knnjz/cc2012xyz2_5_5dp.csv?dl=1) (accessed from http://www.cvrl.org).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("cc2012xyz2_5_5dp.csv", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
horseshoe = np.array([[float(v) for v in l.strip().split(',')] for l in lines])
plt.plot(horseshoe[:,1], horseshoe[:,2])
for i in xrange(14, 47, 4):
    plt.annotate(str(horseshoe[i,0]), xy=horseshoe[i,1:3])
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you post some sample data, or DataFrame? it will be easier for others who try to help

Comment: the example code is perfectly fine, is there any problem you cannot plot the desired output?

Comment: I want to have the ticks as shown in [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/CIE1931xy_blank.svg). By "tick" I mean the small line segments perpendicular to the curve, which can represent data point in the middle of annotated text as well as those near the boundary (where the ticks get much closer to each other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to plot all the ticks yourself, here is an example, it's alot of code.

I set the aspect of the Axes to "equal", otherwise it's difficult to plot ticks perpendicular to the curve:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("cc2012xyz2_5_5dp.csv", header=None)
Labels = df[0].values
X0 = df[1].values
Y0 = df[2].values

ax = plt.gca()

plt.plot(X0, Y0)
ax.set_aspect("equal")

tick_len = 0.015
text_offset = 0.06

idx = np.arange(14, 47, 4)
x, y = X0[idx], Y0[idx]
xp, yp = X0[idx-1], Y0[idx-1]
xn, yn = X0[idx+1], Y0[idx+1]

labels = Labels[idx]
angle = np.arctan2(yn-yp, xn-xp) + np.pi / 2
x1, y1 = x + tick_len*np.cos(angle), y + tick_len*np.sin(angle)
x2, y2 = x + text_offset*np.cos(angle), y + text_offset*np.sin(angle)
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

tick_lines = LineCollection(np.c_[x, y, x1, y1].reshape(-1, 2, 2), color="k", lw=1)
ax.add_collection(tick_lines)
for i in range(len(idx)):
    plt.text(x2[i], y2[i], str(labels[i]), va="center", ha="center")

ax.set_xlim(-0.1, 0.8)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.0)
```

the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, HYRY! That looks great and solves my problem, although I expect some off-the-shelf library in matplotlib that could do the job. I'll wait a couple of days, and accept this answer if nothing else shows up. :)

Comment: Nice answer HYRY! I like it [alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this module for matplotlib.

This should have the information that you need to create the proper ticks.

http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But that module can only manipulate ticks on horizontal or vertical axis, to the best of my current knowledge. Please correct me if I am wrong.